# angular ui routing - avoid hashbang mode. ie9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I'm trying to get html5mode, angular ui routing working in  IE9

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
} else {
    console.log('IE9');
    window.location.hash = '/';  // IE 9 FIX            
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
  .state('placeholder', {
      url: "/path/:myId",
      templateUrl: '../path.html
      controller: 'ResultCtrl'
   }
 );
```

instead of index/path/myid i still get index/#/index/myid which then takes me to index since the browser ignores the hash tag and everything after it. (works in firefox, chrome, edge, IE11-10(browsers supporting html5mode / api history))

Comment: Have you specified base url of application?

Comment: Is this your bug: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/576?

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo yes, i have base url in head.

Comment: @DrColossos not really, i get redirected to whatever was before hashtag, not a blank page.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to using the UI Router, here's what I have in my app:

$locationProvider, which is part of Angular's core, configures an application's paths. By default, Angular prefixes routes with #!, known as Hashbang mode. This is a convention for showing that a page load is triggered by JavaScript.

I added the following code to my config function in app/scripts/app.js file

Add the following code to the config function:

```
    (function() {
      function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode({
              enabled: true,
              requireBase: false
            });
      }
```

By setting the html5Mode method's enabled property to true, the hashbang URLs are disabled; that is, users will see clean URLs without the hashbang. Setting the requireBase property to false is unrelated to the hashbang issue, but is one way to avoid a common $location error.